# R conditional element selection shape

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand how the R `ifelse()` function operates.

```
ifelse(TRUE, "yes", "no")
> "yes"
ifelse(TRUE, 1:10, 2:11)
> 1
```

The R man pages state that the returned value has the same same as the `TEST` argument (here it's the logical `TRUE`).

Is there a way to use `ifelse()` to obtain this behaviour?:

```
ifelse(TRUE, 1:10, 2:11)
> 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  # NOT ACTUAL OUTPUT
```

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized throw the test argument. If the if or else conditions have a length strictly inferior to the length of test argument and divides the test arguments, they are recycled. If you want the last result use the simple if operator `\`if\`(TRUE,1:10, 2:11)`

Answer (score 1):

I often make bugs due to this behavior.  In this case, this gives you the desired outcome.

```
ifelse(TRUE, list(1:10), list(2:11))
```

You can use `unlist` if you need a numeric vector.